# animated boundary visualization of perceptron

Tags: neural-network, data-visualization, perceptron

i buit from scratch the perceptron class in python, and now i'm trying to make the animated visualization of the decision boundary in every iteration of the learning process.The problem is that my code doesn't works, cuz looks like the "animation_func" is not called, i don't know why. can you help me.

```
class Perceptron:
def __init__(self,X=None, y=None,lr=0.001, niter=1000):
    self.lr = lr
    self.niter = niter
    self.w = None
    self.b = None


def fit(self,X,y):
    for indice,X_i in enumerate(X):
        self.w += self.lr*(y_[indice]-self.predic(X_i))* X_i

def animar_perceptron(self,X,y,niter):
    samples,features = X.shape
    self.w = np.zeros(features)
    self.b = 0
    y_ = np.array([1 if i>0 else 0 for i in y])    
    x0_1 = np.amin(X[:,0])
    x0_2 = np.amax(X[:,0])
    ymin = np.amin(X[:,1]) 
    ymax= np.amax(X[:1])    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1],marker='o', c=y )
    boundary, =ax.plot([X0_1, X0_2],[0, 0],'k')
    def animation_func(_):
        self.fit(X,y)
        x1_1 = (-self.w[0]*x0_1-self.b )/self.w[1]
        x1_2 = (-self.w[0]*x0_2-self.b )/self.w[1]
        boundary.set_ydata([x1_1,x1_2])
        return boundary,

    return FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_func, frames=np.arange(1,niter), interval=50)


def predic(self, X):
    y_hat = np.dot(X,self.w) + self.b
    y_hat =self.activate_fun(y_hat)
    return y_hat

def activate_fun(self,z):
    return np.where(z>0, 1,0)

def score(self, y_true, y_pred):
    accuracy = np.sum(y_true == y_pred)/len(y_true)
    return accuracy



p = Perceptron()
animacion = animar_perceptron(X,y,1000)
```

Comment: can you share the error? If isn't, have you tried to bring the animation_func out of animar_perceptron's scope ?

Comment: actually, there is no an error message. i just can't get any thing else different to the first image of the clusters with the initialization boundary.